# Rename: Acceso Denegado, code:5

Tags: php

Estoy intentando mover directorios de una dirección a otra.
Bueno, en realidad intento copiarlos primero, pero eso tampoco ha resultado.
El tema es que, al querer mover los directorios, me aparece el siguiente error.

```
Warning: rename( [...] ): Acceso denegado. (code: 5)
```

Este es el código de momento.

```
// Iniciando TEST de mover carpetas
$dorigen = "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1";
$dfinal = "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/movido/11111111-1";
$contOrigen = scandir($dorigen);
echo "</br>";
//Copiar directorios
if (is_dir($dorigen)) { // Si el directorio existe
    for ($i = 2; $i < count($contOrigen); $i++) { //Recorrelo
        $fecha = $contOrigen[$i]; //Obtenemos las carpetas
        //echo $fecha."</br>";
        if ($fecha < $nuevafecha) { //Si la fecha es anterior a 7 dias
            if (!file_exists($dfinal)) { //Si el directorio final no existe, crealo
                mkdir($dfinal."/".$fecha, 0777, true);
            }
            rename($dorigen."/".$fecha , $dfinal."/".$fecha); //Muevelo
        } else {
            echo "Es reciente </br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Windows, cierto? Pueden ser líos con rename, puede ser algo como lo que indican [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30078367/236345)

Comment: Si, es windows. Pero no entiendo, en la documentacion dice que puede sobreescribirlos [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rename.php). Intentaré aplicar lo mencionado ;)

Comment: @Triby No, esos me los estoy saltando durante el for, nisiquiera los considero por lo mismo.

Comment: @Alfabravo, sigue arrojando el mismo error, además aparece otro `Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`

Comment: @Triby exacto, por ello es que previamente recorro el directorio desde la 2da posicion. Además puedo arrojar var_dump para corroborrar sus posiciones.

Comment: @Triby Comentame eso en una respuesta, para comprender mejor su uso

Comment: Siempre es sano poner sobre qué OS y qué versión de PHP :) Harto va de 5.x a 7

Comment: Windows + PHP 7.3.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer, tu versión de PHP + Windows no permite usar `rename()` para mover carpetas, por lo que es necesario recorrer y copiar cada archivo/directorio manualmente.

Ten en cuenta que `$fecha` es una cadena y no puedes comparar la "antigüedad" en la forma que lo estabas intentando `if ($fecha < $nuevafecha) { //Si la fecha es anterior a 7 dias`, ambas variables deben ser objeto fecha o, al menos, marca de tiempo (timestamp) para poder comparar. Por ahora, está bien usar [marca de tiempo](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/), aunque dejará de funcionar, pero tienes aproximadamente 17 años para hacer las adaptaciones necesarias.

En fin, hay que crear una función para ejecutar de forma recursiva, analizando si el elemento es directorio o moviendo, si se trata de un archivo.

```
function moverCarpetas($dOrigen, $dDestino) {
    if(!is_dir($dOrigen)) {
        return; // No es un directorio
    }
    $contOrigen = scandir($dOrigen);
    foreach($contOrigen as $fecha) {
        if(in_array($fecha, ['.', '..'])) {
            continue; // Omitir no procesables
        }
        if(is_dir("$dOrigen/$fecha")) {
            // Es directorio, validar fecha, ambas como timestamp
            if(strtotime($fecha) < $nuevaFecha) {
                continue; // Es anterior a 7 días, no copiar
            }
            // Verificar que destino existe
            if(!is_dir("$dDestino/$fecha")) {
                mkdir("$dDestino/$fecha", 0777, true);
            }
            // Llamada recursiva
            moverCarpetas("$dOrigen/$fecha", "$dDestino/$fecha");
        } else {
            // Es archivo, mover
            rename("$dOrigen/$fecha", "$dDestino/$fecha");
        }
    }
}
// Fecha actual menos 7 días, en timestamp
$nuevaFecha = strtotime('- 7 days');
// Iniciando TEST de mover carpetas
$dorigen = "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1";
$dfinal = "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/movido/11111111-1";
// Comenzar a mover carpetas
moverCarpetas($dorigen, $dfinal);
```

Comment: A pesar de que lo de las fechas funcione correctamente, no es como debería ser ??? Mis fechas están en formato `"Y-m-d"`Y las comparo con la fecha que trae cada carpeta, hasta ahora funciona bien, incluso hice un debug donde muestro si son anteriores o posteriores, y no hay error alguno.

Comment: La comparación de cadenas no siempre funciona como esperas, por eso es que conviene usar objeto `Date` o `timestamp`, pero tú decides qué método usar.

Comment: Solo debo convertir ambos string a date y ya ??

Comment: Sí, o a `timestamp` con `strtotime()` como en la respuesta.